# Implementation of Asynchronous function call in C

Tags: c, multithreading, async, asynchronous-programming

I took it upon myself recently to work towards making a general-purpose Translator to automatically translate js programs into C, but I got stuck when thinking of asynchronous behaviour. Using ANSI / POSIX C, and only allowing yourself to use a library for a threadpool implementation, how would you go about implementing asynchronous function calls in C. The methodology must be thread-safe. When I came up with my approach, I was inspired by this source's use of what they call the `Asynchronous Dispatcher` pattern: https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/08/04/design-pattern-the-asynchronous-dispatcher/

Comment: What is your approach? I don't see it listed here.

Comment: I purposely omitted my approach to not prejudice any answers, but my approach is an extension of that `Asynchronous Dispatcher` pattern. I posted the question because I am curious to see what people think could be a better implementation.

Comment: Really the question is "How do I improve upon the Asynchronous Dispatcher pattern?". What is wrong with that approach or your current one?

Comment: Well, translating the pattern into C is a bit of a grey area because Java obscures the low-level details that would need to be specified with C, so I haven't actually been able to implement the pattern for thorough testing. So, I am asking to see if there might be an easier, still thread-safe, way to implement this.

Comment: You want to translate to Java or Javascript? Because the question says Javascript (JS) but you just said Java.

Comment: I want to translate from JS to C, I referred to Java because the code in the link I referred to uses Java.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it. Are you aiming a general-purpose Javascript to C translator, or are you just wanting to manually rewrite one particular JS program in C?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973365/threading-in-c

Comment: I'd start clarifying the question, where a certain piece of code asynchronously is called from. Say you have some "system timer" and wish a piece of code be called from the timer after 1100ms. What do you need precisely after 1100ms? A context and a routine. What exactly is calling after 1100ms? And how would you set the timer in the first place? It seems in order to start, you'll have to give a function pointer and again context. When precisely do the threads come in? - Just some thoughts :-) Of course like this, one is building the matchstick castle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you aiming at making a general-purpose Javascript to C automatic translator (that is, a compiler from Javascript to C)?

This is quite challenging and will take you several years of work, in particular if you want to make an efficient Javascript to C compiler (something which won't be much slower than most current Javascript implementations)

Notice that *semantically* Javascript has a lot of common features with [Scheme](http://schemers.org/) (dynamic typing, garbage collection, closures, and perhaps run-time evaluation), even if the syntax is *very different*. Its prototype object model is indeed not in Scheme, but you could find some implementations of prototype object models in Scheme quite similar to the Javascript model. So I definitely recommend studing Scheme and its formal semantics, and looking inside several Scheme to C translators ([Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/), [Chicken](http://call-cc.org/), Stalin, ...). In contrast to Scheme, Javascript was initially ill-defined (its first implementation was a few weeks hack!) and has some unpleasant peculiarities (result of `[] + {}`, etc...) that are painful to handle in a Javascript to C translator.

Then I strongly recommend reading [C.Queinnec *Lisp In Small Pieces*](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.htm) book. Read also [Scott's *programming language pragmatics*](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) book.

The asynchronous aspect of Javascript is similar to [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) and to [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) (a.k.a. CPS). Look into [Continuation Passing C](http://gabriel.kerneis.info/software/cpc/), it is translating a program in CPC (an extended dialect of C, with *yield*, *spawn*, *wait*, ... primitives usable for asynchronous computations) into plain C using continuation passing style techniques.

If your goal is not a general-purpose translator of Javascript to C, but simply to *manually* rewrite a specific Javascript program into C, *coroutines*, [*callbacks*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29), [*closures*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), and CPS are still useful concepts to assess.
And you could even generate or write code for CPC then use the CPC compiler to get ordinary C.

You might also implement your asynchronous computations using the *deprecated* [setcontext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcontext.3.html) routine, but I don't recommend using that since it is deprecated, very low level (basically it is setting all the machine registers), somehow machine specific, and difficult to debug.

Of course you could also consider multi-threading, e.g. [POSIX pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or C11 [threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread).

Comment: I think it's probably safe to assume that the OP isn't attempting to write a generalized JS to C converter.  The only sentence in your answer that appears relevant to the question he asked is the last one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The OP's original question is ambiguous and unclear. Its first sentence suggests on the contrary that he wants to write a general-purpose JS to C compiler.

Comment: Alright, but he's not asking about the general case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: are you sure of that? Apparently he is coding a JS to C translator, at least for some restricted subset of JS.

Comment: *"...but I got stuck when thinking of asynchronous behaviour. Using ANSI / POSIX C, and only allowing yourself to use a library for a threadpool implementation, how would you go about implementing asynchronous function calls in C?"*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch was right, I was referring to the general case. I've edited the question to reflect that.